# Creating a gps application for android

Tags: android, mobile, gps, location

I'm trying to create an app that tracks my location and sends that data to a server to be handled and update my webpage. I'm having a difficult time finding a tutorial that is comprehensive on the "GPS App Development" aspect of it. Creating the tracking app, and collecting the data I need to send to the server, is the main focus at the moment. Handling that data and updating the webpage is a secondary concern; since I assume it will be the easier of the two tasks.

Can anyone recommend a good place to start? Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are many code examples on the internet to get the lat,lon from the gps. So why is this problematic? Further there are many examples to send data to a server on the internet. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use the Google Maps Android API. You can learn about that on [Android Developers MapView page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html). This should probably be the main activity of your application at this point and if you want to make it not the main activity in the future, that shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure how you want to record the data that you mentioned but this should get you started.